# How to convert sql time to hh:mm AM/PM?

Tags: java, android

I have time tag as a created_on="1324987878" ,i want to time as a 5:41 PM.

Comment: @mithun its different not convert in hh:mm:AM

Answer (score 2):

Use SimpleDateFormat API.

```
Date dateObj = new Date(1324987878);
SimpleDateFormat sdfAM = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");
System.out.println(sdfAM.format(dateObj));
```

Output:

```
Jan 16, 1970 01:33 PM
```

Comment: http://dev.thecellcity.com/~alex/FootballKaki/index.php/api/cheers?n_limit=10&n_offset=0&output=dict     i want it from json responce and its come in iphone 5:41 PM how?

Answer (score 2):

Use `SimpleDateFormat`

**Sample Code**

```
long yourmilliseconds = 1324987878;
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm +a");

            Date resultdate = new Date(yourmilliseconds);
            System.out.println(sdf.format(resultdate));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this method, it will return the time as Apr 6, 2011 5:23AM

```
 public static String getTime(long milliseconds)
{

         return DateFormat.format("MMM dd, yyyy h:mmaa", milliseconds).toString();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long created_on = "1324987878";
String pattern = "HH:mm a"
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

Date date = new Date(created_on);
// 5:41 PM
String yourFormatedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
```